# Starting animation after image is loaded (is shown)

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, isolatedstorage

I am using this to load image from uri and then show it with animation (Storyboard) which is defined in .xaml page:

```
var coverBitmap = new BitmapImage(urlToNewCover)
{
    CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.None
};
coverBitmap.ImageOpened += async (s, args) => SetLookFromLoadedBitmap(coverBitmap, track);

    private void SetLookFromLoadedBitmap(BitmapImage coverBitmap, AudioTrack track)
    {
        SetCoverAndBackground(coverBitmap);
        SetLabelsByTrack(track);
        CoverImageSlideIn.Begin();
    }

    private void SetCoverAndBackground(BitmapImage bm)
    {
        ImgAlbumCover.Source = bm;
        ImgAlbumCoverCD.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        ChangeImageForBackground(bm);
    }

    private void ChangeImageForBackground(object s)
    {
        var wb = ImageHelpers.BlurBitmap((BitmapImage)s);
        var brush = new ImageBrush { ImageSource = wb };
        LayoutRoot.Background = brush;
    }
```

It's working and it's okay. But when I tried it with image from Isolated storage the animation isn't started. The image is just shown.

```
var coverBitmap = new BitmapImage();
using (var isf = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
{
     if (isf.FileExists(track.AlbumArt.OriginalString))
     {
          using (var sourceFile = isf.OpenFile(track.AlbumArt.OriginalString, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
          {
              coverBitmap.SetSource(sourceFile);
          }
     }
 }
 SetLookFromLoadedBitmap(coverBitmap, track);
```

What's wrong? How can I fix it? Thanks

Comment: Why don't you use event while loading from isolatedstorage?

Comment: Which event? Because when I tried to add `coverBitmap.ImageOpened += async (s, args) => SetLookFromLoadedBitmap(coverBitmap, track);` to block of code with loading from isolatedstorage and remove line `SetLookFromLoadedBitmap(coverBitmap, track);` then nothing is shown. I guess ImageOpened event is just for images downloaded from internet.

Comment: refer URL: http://suchan.cz/2013/05/image-path-databinding-in-wp8-and-windows-8-apps/  If you use Full image file path as source, may Image Opened Event will raise

Comment: I think your comment would be exactly what I was looking for but can you help me with creating full path in my code? I have something like cover.jpg in track.AlbumArt.OriginalString which is in root of isolated storage. I tried to use `Package.Current.InstalledLocation.Path` or `isostore:/` but I get exception file not found.

Comment: string localFolderPath = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path;
   Path.Combine( localFolderPath, track.AlbumArt.OriginalString ); // wp8 only

Comment: Yea, It's working. Thanks both for help. First who post answer wins :)

Answer (score 0):

My answer, Huh :)

```
string localFolderPath = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path; Path.Combine( localFolderPath, track.AlbumArt.OriginalString );
```